# Native 64bit integers in Javascript

Tags: javascript

It seems that even the newest [Ecmascript 8](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-language-types-number-type) has no support for 64bit integers.

Currently we have to use libraries, like [Long](https://www.npmjs.com/package/long) or [UInt64](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/js-ctypes_reference/UInt64) or [Closure Library](https://google.github.io/closure-library/api/goog.math.Long.html).

Is it technically possible to add native support for 64bit integers in Javascript?

Comment: "All" it takes is a specification change.. it is very much "technically possible", although since such 64-bit integer support is still *not* included, then a library (or equivalent transpilation) is still required..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is. There's a [stage 3](https://tc39.github.io/process-document/) [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bigint) for arbitrary-bigints (including enough to allow implementations to specialize fixed 64-bit use), so it's literally just waiting for implementations and tests at this point. Therefore, one can conclude that it's technically possible.

Comment: Seems very promising: "TypedArrays and DataViews

BigInts give JavaScript the ability to accurately represent 64-bit signed and unsigned integers:

BigUint64Array and BigInt64Array, whose elements read from property access are BigInts
DataView.prototype.getBigInt64/getBigUint64, returning a BigInt
Similarly, BigInts may be used by the WebAssembly FFI for 64-bit arguments and return values to functions." https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bigint

Comment: Is it just me, or is BigInt still incredibly slow in Google Chrome? [This benchmark](https://jsbench.me/aljldbe9a9/1) says BigInt's 64-bit operations are 99% slower than an equivalent 32-bit code. This makes it no more suitable than Long.js or another shim library.