# Native support for 64 bit floating point in Javascript

Tags: javascript, 64-bit, ecmascript-next

As the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45908777/native-64bit-integers-in-javascript) states, even the newest Ecmascript 8 has no support for 64bit integers.

But the [stage 3 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bigint) for bigInt looks promising and I expect it will be added to the Js spec sometime soon.

**However**, Even according to the proposal, we have to use a special constructor for declaring big numbers. **(Q1)** What is the **technical reason behind, being unable to represent big numbers** in the general way?

```
let bigNum = 2 ** 64 // Why can't JS do this without losing precision? (at least in future)
```

I know that *JavaScript represents all numbers using IEEE-754 double-precision (64 bit) floating points* and that this causes the problem.

**(Q2)** Why can't Javascript represent all numbers using *some other standard* which doesn't lose precision?

**(Q3)** What complications would arise if Javascript actually did that?

**Edit**: As stated by T.J, we can use a suffix instead of a constructor, but I still feel that is not exactly the *general notation*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (Q1) What is the technical reason behind, being unable to represent big numbers in the general way?

Breaking the web. The fundamentals of JavaScript numbers cannot be changed now, 20-odd years after they were originally defined. There's also the issue of performance: JavaScript's current numbers (IEEE-754 binary double [64-bit] precision) are **very fast** floating point thanks to being built into CPUs and math coprocessors. The cost of that speed is precision; the cost of arbitrary precision (or a dramatically larger precise range) is performance.

Someday in the future, perhaps JavaScript will get IEEE-754 64-bit or even 128-bit **decimal** floating point numbers (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal64_floating-point_format) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal128_floating-point_format)), if those formats (introduced in 2008) diffuse into the ecosystem and get hardware support. But that's speculation on my part. :-)

> (Q2) Why can't Javascript represent all numbers using some other standard which doesn't lose precision?

See Q1. :-)

> (Q3) What complications would arise if Javascript actually did that?

See Q1. :-)

> Even according to the proposal, we have to use a special constructor for declaring big numbers.

***If*** you want 64-bit specifically. If you just want BigInts, the proposal includes a new notation, the `n` suffix, for that: `2n` is a BigInt 2. So with BigInts, your example would be

```
let bigNum = 2n ** 64n;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Can you elaborate a bit more on how it will **Break the web** if JS does it even without the `n` suffix?

Comment: @PubuduDodangoda: Current code expects IEEE-754 64-bit binary double-precision behavior with JavaScript numbers. So JavaScript numbers must remain IEEE-754 64-bit binary double-precision. Hence the need for something *different*.

Comment: I will accept your answer. But I still don't understand the risk. How would **better precision** break the web?

Comment: @PubuduDodangoda: Again: By changing the semantics of numbers that code is written to expect. Separately, there's also a significant performance cost to BigInt compared to IEEE-754 doubles, which are built into CPUs.